# Change the level of a log4j2 log entry

Tags: log4j2

There is a library class (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter) that logs errors at ERROR level. The message is sometimes irrelevant, because we catch and correct the exception. Moreover, we want to eliminate them in order to create no unnecessary entries in the ticket system or error reports. In other cases, the message may be relevant. The best solution should be if we could change the level of the log entry to WARN.

Is there any way in log4j2 to change the level of an entry based on the logger name, or in other words, to transform the error() calls to warn() calls for a given logger.

Comment: Or perhaps I should use different pattern for different loggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScriptPatternSelector](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Selectors) is a possible solution to this question. Using this construct we can use different patterns according to several aspects. In our case, we can differentiate according to the logger name:

```
    <appenders>
    <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="..."
        filePattern="...">
            <PatternLayout>
                  <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n">
                      <Script name="Log4jPatternSelector" language="bsh"><![CDATA[
                        if (logEvent.getLevel() == org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ERROR
                                && logEvent.getLoggerName().endsWith("JDBCExceptionReporter")) { 
                          return "error_to_warn";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }]]>
                      </Script>
                      <PatternMatch key="error_to_warn" pattern="%d WARN  [%t] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
                  </ScriptPatternSelector>
              </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>
    ...
</appenders>
```

That is, in the pattern for the error messages of JDBCExceptionReporter we use a constant WARN instead of the original priority ERROR.